# How to password model from view to controller in URL.RouteURL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I pass the model from the view Confirm to CareController in URL.RouteURL?

View (Confirm)

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %>

    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmOrder) %>
            </div>

<% } %>

<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "care", action = "process"}) %>
```

CareController

```
public ActionResult Process(ConfirmViewModel model)
{
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Url.RouteUrl for this. That's what the Html.BeginForm is for. It's setup to submit your form to the controller. If you need to change what controller / action it's using then you can pass in additional parameters to Html.BeginForm (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx). Url.RouteUrl will just return a string of the fully qualified URL that you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

Tim had the right idea.  Here's your code sample updated.  There are several overloads for the Html.BeginForm as the MSDN article points out.  You just need to use the one you need.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "CareController" }))
{ %>
     <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

     <div class="editor-field">
          <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmOrder) %>
     </div>
<% } %>
<input type="submit" value="Post">
```